# I can't update the view of the visible Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

My problem, in a nutshell, is: I am calling a method of a fragment before `onResume()` and I don't know why.

I am not using setRetainInstance. I have an activity with a SearchView and a ViewPager. I have also a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which saves 2 fragments in a `List<Fragment>`.

My `SearchView` has the activity as a listener of `OnQueryTextListener`.
When I submit, inside the listener `onQueryTextSubmit` I call:

```
//make changes in shared preferences
Fragment fragment = mAdapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
((View) fragment).onLocationChange();
```

The implementation of `onLocationChange` in each fragment is:

```
@Override
  public void onLocationChange() {
    //avoid null pointer when is called too early in the life cycle
    if (isResumed()) {
      onResume();
    }
  }
```

The problem is sometimes `isResumed` is suddenly false so I can't update the view of the visible Fragment. I can see the changes only changing my current tab and detecting the change in the fragment:

```
@Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
    // Make sure that fragment is currently visible
    if (isVisible && isResumed()) {
      onResume();
    }
  }
```

Why might is not work sometimes? My `onResume` looks like:

```
@Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!getUserVisibleHint()) {
      return;
    }
    //work here
  }
```

Comment: So far geting the fragment from getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() seems to work well.

Comment: it's not a good idea to call onResume() manually.

Comment: Thanks for that @minhazur. Now I call a method instead of onResume.